# how to use truffle to read state value of a smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, ether, truffle-deployment

I'm a newbie.

I have following dummy contract

```
contract A{

uint public test = 6;
address public myaddress;
uint public dummy;

/**
* The logs that will be emitted in every step of the contract's life cycle
*/
event MyEvent(address myaddress);
event ReadEvent(address myaddress, uint dummy);

/**
* The contract constructor
*/
constructor() public {
    myaddress = msg.sender;
    emit MyEvent(myaddress);
}

function myF(address sender, uint value) internal {
    require(sender == myaddress );
    dummy = value;
    emit ReadEvent(sender, myaddress);

}


function run() public payable{
    myF(msg.sender, msg.value);

    /*SendMiles();*/

}
}
```

I then compile it and migrate using truffle. After I start a truffle console on a development network and do the following:

```
A.deployed().then(inst => { AInstance = inst })

account0 = web3.eth.accounts[0];

AInstance.run({from: account0, value: 5});
```

I then get a transaction number '0xa72b03232f5028332411d7f05cf47248616aab96d982ce9a7b147a00642db405' on glinche.

Two questions:
1. How can i get the contract variables value mainly for test, myaddress and dummy for transaction '0xa72b03232f5028332411d7f05cf47248616aab96d982ce9a7b147a00642db405'

2. How can I get those values in a more complex format like json?

I tried the web3.eth.storeat and A.at('0xa72b03232f5028332411d7f05cf47248616aab96d982ce9a7b147a00642db405') and it didnt work in both cases

thanks in advance;

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction '0xa72b0...' modify the state of the contract A. Contract public variables such as myaddress are stored in the state of your contract: asking to get myaddress for a specific transaction has no sense.

1. In solidity, giving a variable the `public` attribute automatically generate a getter function of the same name: you can get myaddress value with the command: `AInstance.myaddress()`
2. You can manually generate JSON:

   ```
   var tmp = new Object()
   tmp.test = AInstance.test()
   tmp.myaddress = AInstance.myaddress()
   tmp.dummy = AInstance.dummy()
   result = JSON.stringify(tmp)
   ```

Comment: 1. if I understand this correctly, there is one contract and each transaction updates the state in that contract? so if I initiate  2 contracts A from 2 different accounts, A.instance.myaddress() will have the address of the second instance?
2. how do I initiate an instance on a particular transaction on the blockchain and get its values?
3. is there a way to automatically turn on the states in all transactions into one text files without using truffle, geth or any web3 applications?

Comment: Your first phrase is correct. However I feel that the difference between a contract and a contract instance is not clear for you. When you execute `AInstance.run()` you are calling the method `run` from the specific instance `AInstance` of your contract `A`. If you deploy again you will get another instance of your contract `A`.

Comment: so everytime you deploy a contract you get an instance. This instance then will have one or more transaction, correct? So in that case I guess I'm trying to understand at a current transaction, what is the value of that instance, correct?